React-native Gradle upgrade incompatible kotlin version / where does build.gradle.kts version come from
I keep getting this error while trying to build my react native android app
The class is loaded from /{homeDir}/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.5-bin/5t9huq95ubn472n8rpzujfbqh/gradle-8.5/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.20.jar!/kotlin/collections/CollectionsKt__CollectionsJVMKt.class
e: /{projectDir}/node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactExtension.kt: (103, 72): Class 'kotlin.reflect.KClass' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

I have tried setting the kotlin version in build.gradle and gradle.properties, both to 1.7.1., 1.7.22 and 1.9.0 (plus a few other versions just to try).
If I go into  {projectDir}/node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin/build.gradle.kts and manually change the kotlin version to 1.9.0, then it will build.
Does anyone know why this is or where the value of that file is set from.
Thank you.
